# Постоянные ссылки Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть сайт на котором хочу сделать следующую структуру ссылок:

```
http://example.com/category-name/sub-category-name/post-name.html
```

Установлен плагин YoastSEO, в настройках WP установлена произвольная структура ссылок - `/%category%/%postname%.html`

Но при таком варианте отображается только основная категория, без подкатегории. 
Единственное, на странице редактирования Записи, при выборе категории есть кнопка "Сделать первичным" (см. скриншот ниже). Если выбрать Подкатегорию первичной, она отображается как и нужно, но тогда страница доступна по двум адресам
http://example.com/category-name/sub-category-name/post-name.html
http://example.com/category-name/post-name.html

Как можно получить желаемую структуру без дублирования?
[image: выбор рубрики в для Записи]

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30350/sub-category-and-category-in-permalink-structure

Comment: Супер СПАСИБО! Как всегда, "дьявол кроется в деталях" :) Я просто пробовал похожий вариант, но не находил информации, что нужно в таком случае выбрать только подкатегорию