# Формирование иерархии ссылок Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите такой вопрос нужно сформировать примерно такую иерархию ссылок
`http://site.com/services/services-cat/service-post/bmw/`

1. `services/` - допустим это CPT;
2. `services-cat/` - допустим это taxonomy;
3. `service-post/` - ну а это post;
4. `bmw/` - как это реализовать?

Проблема заключается в том, что сюда `http://site.com/services/services-cat/service-post/bmw/` можно попасть не только так:

- `http://site.com/services/`
- `http://site.com/services/services-cat/`
- `http://site.com/services/services-cat/service-post/`
- `http://site.com/services/services-cat/service-post/bmw/`

Так же могут быть промежуточные ссылки:

- `http://site.com/services/bmw/`
- `http://site.com/services/services-cat/bmw/`
- `http://site.com/services/services-cat/service-post/bmw/`

Наверное стоит дополнить вопрос:

- `http://site.com/services/` - эта страница содержит список категорий услуг (для всех марок авто)
- `http://site.com/services/services-cat/` - эта страница содержит весь список услуг (для всех марок авто)
- `http://site.com/services/services-cat/service-post/` - эта страница содержит описание об услуге (для всех марок авто)
- `http://site.com/services/services-cat/service-post/bmw/` - эта страница содержит описание об услуге (только для BMW)
- `http://site.com/services/bmw/` - эта страница содержит список категорий услуг (только для BMW)
- `http://site.com/services/services-cat/bmw/` - эта страница содержит весь список услуг (только для BMW)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/738749/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-wordpress?noredirect=1#comment1127565_738749

Comment: спасибо, я читал этот пост, но вы наверное не вникли в суть вопроса

Comment: Нужно сделать "примерно такую иерархию ссылок http://site.com/services/services-cat/service-post/bmw/" и чтобы можно было обращаться только по такой ссылки, без промежуточных? Или наоборот?

Comment: `Так же могут быть промежуточные ссылки:` обратите внимание на этот пункт

Comment: на странице `service-post` выводится описание услуги, а на странице `service-post/bmw/` - список услуг для BMW

Comment: я дополнил вопрос

Comment: Видел, но чет все рано для меня не понятно что вам нужно xD

Comment: "Проблема заключается в том, что сюда http://site.com/services/services-cat/service-post/bmw/ можно попасть не только так" - Нужно решить эту проблему? Вы говорите что не так понял вопрос.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68162/discussion-between-eugene-v-and-).